# Python 3, http.client HTTP error 400

Tags: http, python-3.x, imdb

I've been working on a small pet project where I am using http.client to communicate (sorry if that's bad terminology, feel free to correct me) with [omdbapi](http://www.omdbapi.com/). From here I access the data on the website using the following code:

```
import http.client, json
__connection = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.omdbapi.com")

def getDetailsFromTitle(title):
    __connection.request("GET", "/?t=" + title)
    return __processRequest()

def getDetailsFromID(id):
     __connection.request("GET", "/?i=" + id)
     return __processRequest()

def __processRequest():
    try:
        response = __connection.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        return json.loads(data)
except: return None
```

This worked fine for my first few trials, like I was able to get all my data back properly if I looked up say "Eureka", or "Superbad"; however, as soon as I inputted "Bad Kids Go To Hell" my try in __processRequest was being broken and None was being returned. 
The data I managed to get from the request was:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

It's obviously breaking on the json.loads(data) as data isn't what is expected, but I'm not overly sure why I'm receiving this error. I went to the website and inputted "Bad Kids Go To Hell" and all worked fine.

Please let me know if you need anything more to assist me,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the parameter lists of your urls, you should use `[urlencode()][1]`. In this case it's likely the spaces in the string that causes the problem, they should be converted to '+' characters.

```
__connection.request("GET", "/"+(urlencode({'t': title})
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this and will keep it in mind in future.
I've modified my code as you've suggested and it has produced a different error:
<h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>

EDITED: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong test when I replied. I am given this error for all of my look ups. I will attempt to debug through it and find a resolution when I next get a chance.
Cheers.